# sqlalchemy tries to create my tables twice

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

sqlalchemy searches my tables twice.

I've been looking for a problem all day, but I can't find it

**apps/books/models**

```
print('before')


class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = Column(String, nullable=False,unique=True)
    descriptions = Column(String)
    file_path = Column(String,unique=True)

    users = relationship("User", secondary="book_users", back_populates='books')

book_users = Table('book_users', Base.metadata,
    Column('book_id', ForeignKey('books.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('users_id', ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True),
)
print('after')

class Part(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    descriptions = Column(String)
    
    book_id = Column('book_id',ForeignKey('books.id'))
    book = relationship('Book',backref='parts')
```

**apps/users/models**

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True)
    last_name = Column(String)
    hashed_password = Column(String)

    books = relationship("Book", secondary="book_users", back_populates='users')
```

**apps/database**

```
from decouple import config

USER = config('user')
PASSWORD = config('password')
DB = config('db')
HOST = config('host')


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}/{DB}"


engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


Base = declarative_base()

def get_db():
    db = Session(bind=engine)
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

im tryed without decouple,it didn't help

**apps/main**

```
import sys,os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(".."))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("..."))

from fastapi import FastAPI
from database import engine, Base

from users.routers import router as router_user
from books.routers import router as router_book

def create_db():
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI(title="Shop")

@app.on_event("startup")
def on_startup():
    create_db()

app.include_router(router=router_user)
app.include_router(router=router_book)
```

inserts is only one way for my imports)

**exception**

```
before
after
before
Process SpawnProcess-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1501, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 458, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/apps/./main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from books.routers import router as router_book
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/apps/./books/routers.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .models import Book, Part
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/apps/./books/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Book(Base):
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_api.py", line 72, in __init__
    _as_declarative(reg, cls, dict_)
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 126, in _as_declarative
    return _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(registry, cls, dict_, None, {})
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 177, in setup_mapping
    return cfg_cls(registry, cls_, dict_, table, mapper_kw)
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 322, in __init__
    self._setup_table(table)
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 811, in _setup_table
    table_cls(
  File "<string>", line 2, in __new__
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 309, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kana/Desktop/author/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 584, in __new__
    raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'books' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

how you can look, my program broken in **apps/books/models** after

class Book(Base)

if i switch Book and Part, error will be in Part

any hint will be gratefully accepted

Comment: You can't guarantee that your application will only be started once by uvicorn. You'll see it started once as the application starts, then in each worker process - if you run with reload as well it will be restarted every time you make a change. Instead of relying on your application only starting once, you'll be better off by using a migration system like alembic instead of `create_db` - this will also work when you already have data in an existing database. Is that an option?

Comment: The error states that the _class_ `Book` is being created twice (and so the `Table` instance for it). This sounds like you might be importing your module twice using different paths, leading to it being evaluated and its contents being created twice. The `sys.path` twiddlings make it seem more possible.

Comment: about alembic, - im just beginner, in the future I will definitely switch to alembic, but now its not an option

@MatsLindh thx for recommendation

Comment: @IljaEverilä i love you so much <3
I've reworked all the imports and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encounter this problem, you need to thoroughly change every import in your program, specifying the same path from the root directory everywhere.

another reason for the problem may be the architecture of the project.

my first reason why my database didn't create tables is because it was on the same level as the tables. in my case, it was in **apps/utils/main** when the tables were at the **apps/books/models**
level, he added it to Base.metadata.tables, but when he moved to **apps/utils/main** the Base.metadata.tables list was empty.
when I pulled it to the current level, the problem disappeared

resume:

string **Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)** must be a level higher than module **models** (or another name your models)

and update your imports

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).